# Firebase: NotificationCompat.Builder error

Tags: java, android, notifications

I got an error of `Notification.Builder` and I don't know why this is the error:

[image]

This is my gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'

    // [START gradle_play_config]
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'


}
```

I'm searching the whole time but I only found that it should be android 26 and up but I still got error.

Comment: You are using as a first parameter something that's not a context. Context objects are activities, application, service, and content provider (broadcast receivers have context but are not context). Ensure your class inherits from a service and use the method getContext of the service if this doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

[**`NotificationCompat.Builder`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder) constructor takes `String channelId` as the second paramater.

So, try getting the `String` directly:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 
        getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
        ... 
        ..
```

Or if this didn't help, try this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
        ... 
        ..
```

Check this link:  [NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID) not working on Oreo Firebase notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567676/notificationcompat-buildergetapplicationcontext-channel-id-not-working-on-o)

Comment: How about adding `getResources()` then: `getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)` ? You can however set a string like this to see  if that solves the issue: `..Builder(this, "test")` // or `CHANNEL_ID` Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567676/notificationcompat-buildergetapplicationcontext-channel-id-not-working-on-o

Comment: It should work with these changes. However, you may want to update your support library to `27.1.1` or `28.0.0` **Or** do a rebuild-clean project since it has been depreciated in 26.1.0 And I suspect it might not well set in the `26.1.1`. (Worth to try)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with your dependencies. The error just says that you are passing a MyFirebaseMessagingService instead of a context.
Try by:

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext, channelId)...
```

or edit your post and show in which class you are doing this (and write the error, don't use an image).

Comment: The `Context` isn't red as you can see. Check my answer.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. However, the channelId is a String, so it shouldn't be that either.

Comment: Hello, Actually Im following the firebase messaging tutorial.