# How do I setup an Android Notification Channel?

Tags: android, service, notifications, channel

I looked at the example code [Android "Create a Notification" example](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) and created my own version of it:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

...

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, (String) CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Eumag")
            .setContentText("foreground service running")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
```

However, that yielded this error when I tried to build the project:

> error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given
>   types; required: Context found: ForegroundService,String reason:
>   actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I did some research and found out that it means that there is no constructor that accept the given parameters.  So I looked into the [NotificationCompat.Builder documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setChannelId(java.lang.String)).  According to the docs, both of the following methods should exist, but in the source code, only one of them does:

NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context) **[Exists]**
NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId) **[Doesn't Exist]**

That's fine I guess, so I go try an alternative which is "setChannelId(String channelId)" and that's not in there either!  I AM CONFUSION.

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.eumag"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':spotify-app-remote')
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1"
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.github.spotify:android-auth:9425c6a140'
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Which version of the support libraries are you using? Note that [the two-parameter constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#NotificationCompat.Builder(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) wasn't added until version 26.1.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL\_ID) not working on Oreo Firebase notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567676/notificationcompat-buildergetapplicationcontext-channel-id-not-working-on-o)

Comment: My build.gradle doesn't look like his though... I'm assuming I need to implement the most recent support library then?  If so, how do I go about doing that?